# Create instance of generic type with pointer to type parameter

Tags: go, generics

Given these type definitions:

```
type N interface{ ~int | ~float32 | ~float64 }

type S[T any] struct {
    t T
}

type myInt int

type pSpMyInt[T myInt] *S[*T]
type spMyInt[T *myInt,] S[T]
type spMyInt2[T myInt] S[*T]
```

I can create a var of `type pSpMyInt` with

```
func createPS[T myInt]() pSpMyInt[T] {
    var i T
    s := S[*T]{t: &i}
    return &s
}
```

But I can not figure out how to create vars of `spMyInt` or `spMyInt2`.

This

```
func createSP[T myInt]() spMyInt2[T] {
    var i T
    s := S[*T]{t: &i}
    return s
}
```

fails to compile
`cannot use s (variable of type S[*T]) as type spMyInt2[T] in return statement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, *do NOT use exact type parameter constraints*. It almost never makes sense. When you declare a function as `createPS[T myInt]()`, the type parameter type set has cardinality 1, so it can effectively be instantiated **only** and **ever** by `myInt`. You could rewrite the function like the following just as fine:

```
func createPS() pSpMyInt[myInt] {
    var i myInt
    s := S[*myInt]{t: &i}
    return &s
}
```

With that out of the way:

The type `S[*T]` **is just not the same** as `spMyInt2[T]`. However, since `spMyInt2[T]`'s underlying type is `S[*T]`, you can simply convert:

```
func createSP2[T myInt]() spMyInt2[T] {
    var i T
    s := S[*T]{t: &i}
    return spMyInt2[T](s) // conversion
}
```

---

As for `type spMyInt[T *myInt,] S[T]` (where the comma is not a typo but is needed to avoid a parsing ambiguity), the thing isn't that simple.

The problem is that a type parameter **is not** its type constraint. Therefore type literals can't be used to instantiate different unnamed type literals. To be clear:

```
// naive attempt that doesn't compile
func createSP1[T myInt]() spMyInt[*T] {
    var i T
    s := S[*T]{t: &i}
    return spMyInt[*T](s)
}
```

You might think that `spMyInt[T *myInt]` has a type parameter constrained to `*myInt` and the function `T` is constrained by the base type `myInt`, *therefore* `*T` should satisfy `T *myInt`. This is not correct for the apparently unobvious reason that the type literal `*T` is not equivalent to `*myInt`. So actually you can't write a generic constructor for `type spMyInt[T *myInt,] S[T]`.

However you are in luck because the type constraint had cardinality one. So you can just remove the type parameter:

```
func createSP1() spMyInt[*myInt] {
    var i myInt
    s := S[*myInt]{t: &i}
    return spMyInt[*myInt](s)
}
```